# TypeError: Cannot read property 'chat' of undefined, problem inline keyboard

Tags: node.js

I have this problem, I would like to create a keyboard for my telegram bot, here is my code, where I created the keys with online keyboard. It gives me this error and I can't connect it to my posts, where the word was posted to / news

```
const util = require('util');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// includiamo la libreria "axios"
const axios = require('axios');

// Includiamo la libreria "body-parser" per gestire le richieste in JSON.
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.get ('/', function (req, res) {
   res.status (200) .json ({status: 'ok'});
});

// Includiamo il modulo "request" per effettuare richieste HTTP
const https = require('https');


// Webhook per Telegram
 app.post('/', function (req, res)  {
  console.log("Richiesta: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  const chatid = req.body.message.chat.id;
  const text = req.body.message.text;
  const username = req.body.message.from.username

  console.log("Utente in chat " + chatid + " ha scritto '" + text + "'");


 const clientreq = https.request({
   method: 'POST',
   host: 'api.telegram.org',
   url: 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'+process.env.BOTTOKEN+'/setWebhook? 
   url=https://viktecnews.glitch.me/',
   path: '/bot' + process.env.BOTTOKEN + '/getMe'
    },function(resp) {
   // Questa funzione viene richiamata a richiesta eseguita
   if(resp.statusCode != 200) {
   console.log("Richiesta HTTP fallita");
    return;
  }
 console.log("Richiesta HTTP riuscita");


   var body = '';
  resp.on('data', function(d) {
      body += d;
   });
    resp.on('end', function() {
  // Ora body contiene il contenuto (corpo) della risposta
  console.log("Risposta da API Telegram: " + body);


  const j = JSON.parse(body);
  // j è un oggetto JavaScript che contiene i dati della risposta
  // ...
    });
 }); 


  if (text.match(/start/)) 

  { axios.post ('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+ 
             process.env.BOTTOKEN+'/sendMessage' 
,
               {
               chat_id: chatid,
               text: 'Benvenuto'+'\t'+ username +'\t' + 'in ViktecNews, 
  scopri le ultime news sul mondo della tecnologia, guide e recensioni. 
   Per qualsiasi cosa vai su info',
               reply_markup: JSON.stringify ({ 
                 inline_keyboard:[[
                   {
      text: 'news',
      callback_data: '/news'
    },{
      text: 'recensioni',
      callback_data: '/recensioni'
    },{
      text: 'guide',
      callback_data: '/guide'
    },{
      text: 'info',
      callback_data: '/info'
    }
                 ]]
               })
    }).then(response => { 
    // Messaggio postato 
     console.log('Message posted')
       console.log()
  res.end('ok')
})
.catch(err => {
  // ...Messaggio non postato
  console.log('Error :', err)
  res.end('Error :' + err)
    })
}
 else if (text.match(/info/)) {
     axios.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+
    process.env.BOTTOKEN+'/sendMessage' 
  ,
                 {
               chat_id: chatid,
               text: 'ViktecNews è un bot programmato per riportarti le 
   ultime dieci news, guide e recensioni. Per qualsiasi problema contatta 
 @viktec'
               })
        .then(response => {
      // Messaggio postato
      console.log('Message posted')
     res.end('ok')
   })
   .catch(err => {
       // ...Messaggio non postato
      console.log('Error :', err)
       res.end('Error :' + err)
     })

     }

  else if (text.match (/news/)) { 
       axios.get( URL ,{
        params: {
       categories: '8240'
        }
      })
  .then(response => {
        for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++)
   axios.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+
   process.env.BOTTOKEN+'/sendMessage' 
   ,
               {
                  chat_id: chatid,
               text: response.data[i].title.rendered +" \n\t"+ 
  response.data[i].link + " \n\t"+"Autore : "+response.data[i].author
               })
      .then(response => {
  // Messaggio postato  
  console.log('Message posted')
  res.end('ok')
   })
     .catch(err => {
    // ...Messaggio non postato
    console.log('Error :', err)
     res.end('Error :' + err)
  })
  console.log(response.data[0]);
  })
  .catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
  });

 }else if (text.match (/recensioni/)) { 
    axios.get( URL ,{
     params: {
       categories: '8241'
     }
     })
  .then(response => {
       for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++)
    axios.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+
    process.env.BOTTOKEN+'/sendMessage',
               {
               chat_id: chatid,
               text: response.data[i].title.rendered +" \n\t"+ 
  response.data[i].link + " \n\t"+"Autore : "+response.data[i].author
               })
      .then(response => {
  // Messaggio postato  
  console.log('Message posted')
  res.end('ok')
   })
  .catch(err => {
  // ...Messaggio non postato
  console.log('Error :', err)
  res.end('Error :' + err)
   })
  console.log(response.data[0]);
  })
  .catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
  });

 } else if (text.match (/guide/)) { 
   axios.get( URL ,{
     params: {
       categories: '8250'
     }
     })
 .then(response => {
     for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++)


  axios.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+
  process.env.BOTTOKEN+'/sendMessage' ,
               {
               chat_id: chatid,
               text: response.data[i].title.rendered +" \n\t"+ 
 response.data[i].link + " \n\t"+"Autore : "+response.data[i].author
                })
      .then(response => {
   // Messaggio postato  
   console.log('Message posted')
   res.end('ok')
   })
   .catch(err => {
  // ...Messaggio non postato
  console.log('Error :', err)
   res.end('Error :' + err)
  })
  console.log(response.data[0]);
  })
 .catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
 });

   } else if (text.match (/games/)) { 
      axios.get( URL ,{
     params: {
       categories: '8245'
     }
     })
   .then(response => {
      for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++)





      axios.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+
    process.env.BOTTOKEN+'/sendMessage',
               {
               chat_id: chatid,
               text: response.data[i].title.rendered +" \n\t"+ 
     response.data[i].link + " \n\t"+"Autore : "+response.data[i].author
               })
      .then(response => {
  // Messaggio postato  
  console.log('Message posted')
  res.end('ok')
  })
   .catch(err => {
  // ...Messaggio non postato
  console.log('Error :', err)
  res.end('Error :' + err)
   })
   console.log(response.data[0]);
 })
 .catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
 });

  }else 




      {axios.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+
      process.env.BOTTOKEN+'/sendMessage 
,
               {
                chat_id: chatid,
               text: "Carattere errato, utilizza i comandi!"
  })
 .then(response => {
  // Messaggio postato
  console.log('Message posted')
  res.end('ok')
    })
   .catch(err => {
  // ...Messaggio non postato
  console.log('Error :', err)
  res.end('Error :' + err)
    })}; 
  clientreq.end(); // questa chiamata esegue la richiesta 
 });



 const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + 
listener.address().port);
 });`
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'chat' of undefined

at /app/server.js:22:35

```
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/rbd/pnpm-volume/f9d011c8-bafe-411e-a616-958a5a1a748d/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.16.4/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

at next (/rbd/pnpm-volume/f9d011c8-bafe-411e-a616-958a5a1a748d/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.16.4/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)

at Route.dispatch (/rbd/pnpm-volume/f9d011c8-bafe-411e-a616-958a5a1a748d/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.16.4/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)

at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/rbd/pnpm-volume/f9d011c8-bafe-411e-a616-958a5a1a748d/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.16.4/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

at /rbd/pnpm-volume/f9d011c8-bafe-411e-a616-958a5a1a748d/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.16.4/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22

at Function.process_params (/rbd/pnpm-volume/f9d011c8-bafe-411e-a616-958a5a1a748d/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.16.4/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)

at next (/rbd/pnpm-volume/f9d011c8-bafe-411e-a616-958a5a1a748d/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/express/4.16.4/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)

at /rbd/pnpm-volume/f9d011c8-bafe-411e-a616-958a5a1a748d/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/body-parser/1.19.0/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5

at invokeCallback (/rbd/pnpm-volume/f9d011c8-bafe-411e-a616-958a5a1a748d/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/raw-body/2.4.0/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that `message` is undefined.  Please make sure the client is providing `message` as part of the POST body.

Comment: Can you provide the console output starting with "Richiesta:"?

Comment: Richiesta: {"update_id":542110369,"callback_query":{"id":"601936097613333642","from":{"id":140149169,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"- Vik -","username":"viktec","language_code":"it"},"message":{"message_id":1517,"from":{"id":871275873,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"ViktecNews","username":"ViktecNews_bot"},"chat":{"id":1401491,"first_name":"- Vik -","username":"viktec","type":"private"},"date":1559292386,"text":"Benvenuto viktec in ViktecNews, scopri le ultime news sul mondo della tecnologia, guide e recensioni. Per qualsiasi cosa vai su info"},"chat_instance":"-2385285007993537149","data":"/news"}}

Comment: first request is this, then give me that other request

Richiesta: {"update_id":542110374,"message":{"message_id":1548,"from":{"id":140149169,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"- Vik -","username":"viktec","language_code":"it"},"chat":{"id":140149169,"first_name":"- Vik -","username":"viktec","type":"private"},"date":1559293442,"text":"/start","entities":[{"offset":0,"length":6,"type":"bot_command"}]}}

Comment: Based on the first request you listed, `message` is nested under `callback_query`

Comment: in fact the first request is normal, then I get the callback_query. the problem is that first I need the first costs then these other costs, how could I manage and adjust the code?

Comment: const chatid = req.body.message.chat.id;
      const text = req.body.message.text;
      const username = req.body.message.from.username


    const chatid = req.body.callback_query.from.id; 
    const text = req.body.callback_query.data;
    const username = 
     req.body.callback_query.from.username

Comment: why? have a idea?